# Over partition in more than 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to pl/sql and I need your help
I want to make a sum over partition to the `table1.col1`
but I don't know how.

My simple query is like the following:

```
SELECT TABLE3.COL1, TABLE2.COL1,  TABLE1.COL1 
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE TABLE1.COL1 = TABLE2.COL1
AND TABLE3.COL1 = TABLE2.COL1;
```

Result:

```
1  1    100
1  2    100
1  2    200
1  2    100
2  4    200
```

I want the query to return:

```
1  1    100
1  2    400
2  4    200
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Why is `500` in the second row? Is it just typo?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need a stored procedure or window function. This looks like a basic `group by` statement:

```
SELECT table3.col1, table2.col1, sum(table1.col1)
FROM TABLE1
   JOIN table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1
   JOIN table3 ON table3.col1 = table2.col1
GROUP BY table3.col1, table2.col1
```

---

<sup>Note that I replaced the old-fashioned implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause with a proper explicit `JOIN` operator</sup>